How to make all new tabs/windows in electron direct to new electron-tabs
I'm currently working on some JavaScript code for a project. My goal is to make Electron open all links that would normally result in "pop-ups" to open in new tabs under the electron-tabs package.
I'm fairly new to js/electron, but after a few hours of debugging I'm at a loss. I'm not sure if the mouse-click-listener needs to go into the app.js or main.html file, but either way I can't seem to get anything to work - below is a snippet:
app.js:
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;

app.on("ready", function () {
  const mainWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      webviewTag: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/main.html");
});

main.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Explorer</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0">

<tab-group new-tab-button="true" sortable="true">
  <style>
    /* Add custom styles */
    .my-badge {
      background-color: #Green;
    }
    .my-custom-tab {
      color: #d135d1;
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
</tab-group>

<script src="node_modules/electron-tabs/dist/electron-tabs.js"></script>
<script>
  const tabGroup = document.querySelector("tab-group");
  
tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Function Designer",
    src: "https://localhost",
    active: true
  });

  tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "UI Designer",
    src: "https://localhost/ui-designer",
    active: true,
  });

  tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Configuration Browser",
    src: "https://localhost/configuration-browser",
    active: true
  });

  tabGroup.addTab({
    title: "Documentation Browser",
    src: "https://localhost/documentation-browser",
    active: true
  });

tabGroup.setDefaultTab({
    title: "Function Designer",
    src: "https://localhost",
    active: true
  });

document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
      const clickedLinkURL = event.target.href;
      tabGroup.addTab({
        title: "New Tab",
        src: clickedLinkURL
      });
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>

I want to write a click listener and forward all clicks that would normally result in new tabs on chrome/Firefox, to result in new tabs under the electron-tabs package. I cannot seem to do this.
Edit: Forgot to mention, I also read the documentation for Electron-Tabs and I didn’t see anything remotely close to what I needed.
